# Trying to convert assembly instructions for switch statement into c code

Tags: assembly, switch-statement, translate

I'm trying to find the equivalent c code for the assembly instructions for this function.

Assembly instructions:

```
0x400698: 0x00000000004005ad 0x00000000004005c3  
0x4006a8: 0x00000000004005c3 0x00000000004005c3  
0x4006b8: 0x00000000004005a8 0x00000000004005be  
0x4006c8: 0x00000000004005a8 0x00000000004005b7


   0x000000000040057c <+0>:     push   %rbp
   0x000000000040057d <+1>:     mov    %rsp,%rbp
   0x0000000000400580 <+4>:     mov    %rdi,-0x18(%rbp)
   0x0000000000400584 <+8>:     mov    %rsi,-0x20(%rbp)
   0x0000000000400588 <+12>:    mov    -0x20(%rbp),%rax
   0x000000000040058c <+16>:    mov    %rax,-0x8(%rbp)
   0x0000000000400590 <+20>:    mov    -0x18(%rbp),%rax
   0x0000000000400594 <+24>:    sub    $0x52,%rax
   0x0000000000400598 <+28>:    cmp    $0x7,%rax
   0x000000000040059c <+32>:    ja     0x4005c3 <switch_prob+71>
   0x000000000040059e <+34>:    mov    0x400698(,%rax,8),%rax
   0x00000000004005a6 <+42>:    jmpq   *%rax
   0x00000000004005a8 <+44>:    subq   $0xa,-0x8(%rbp)
   0x00000000004005ad <+49>:    movq   $0x3e,-0x8(%rbp)
   0x00000000004005b5 <+57>:    jmp    0x4005cb <switch_prob+79>
   0x00000000004005b7 <+59>:    sarq   $0x4,-0x8(%rbp)
   0x00000000004005bc <+64>:    jmp    0x4005cb <switch_prob+79>
   0x00000000004005be <+66>:    subq   $0x1,-0x8(%rbp)
   0x00000000004005c3 <+71>:    movq   $0x3b,-0x8(%rbp)
   0x00000000004005cb <+79>:    mov    -0x8(%rbp),%rax
   0x00000000004005cf <+83>:    pop    %rbp
   0x00000000004005d0 <+84>:    retq
```

I'm trying to recover the cases in the switch statement. I'm new to assembly switch statements.
my code so far (most guessing):

```
long switch_prob(long x, long n){
    long result = n;
    switch(x){
        case 82:
            break;
        case 7:
            break;
        case 89:
            break;
        case 59:
            break;
        case 87:

        default:
            break;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

After the sub $82 it checks if the result is greater than 7. If it is, it goes to the default case. Otherwise it jumps through the jump table, so the cases are 82 - 89. Some of those cases have the same code, and some also fall through to the following case.